# problema con ciclo

Tags: python, python-3.x

amigos necesito separar el primer dígito para un numero leído pero no he sido capaz con lo que he hecho siempre me separa el ultimo:

```
try:
    numero=int(input("Digite un numero entero:"))

    suma=0

    for i in str(numero):
        suma= i 
    print(i)

except ValueError:
    print("El valor digitado debe ser numerico")
```

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener el primer dígito o la suma de los dígitos del número? Para obtener el primer digito basta con indexar sobre la cadena: `d = str(numero)[0]`. Te imprime el último dígito porque `i` es la variable del `for` y cuando el ciclo termina de iterar sobre la cadena, `i` contendrá el último carácter de la misma.

Comment: quiero imprimir el primer digito solamente sin importar de cuantas cifras sea el numero leido pero he intentado de muchas maneras y nada

Comment: gracias amigo por tu respuestas estaba un poco enredado